# Convergence of an integral with powers

Tags: calculus

Is my line of reasoning correct?
$ \int_0^n {x^p / (x^2 + 1)^q} dx $ as n goes to infinity. Prove that it converges. Well $x^p$ is asymptotical to $x^p$, and $(x^2+1)^q$ is asymptotical to $x^{2q}$, we get an integral from $0$ to infinity of $x^{p-2q}$, since it diverges and is asymptotical to first one, the first one diverges too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the integrand is non-negative in $(0,+\infty)$ we can use the asymptotic comparison test and check the convergence in a neighborhood of $+\infty$ and in a right neighborhood of $0$.

For $x\to +\infty$,
$$\frac{x^p}{(x^2 + 1)^q}\sim \frac{1}{x^{2q-p}},$$ 
hence the integral in $[1,+\infty)$ is convergent iff $2q-p>1$.

For $x\to 0^+$,
$$\frac{x^p}{(x^2 + 1)^q}\sim \frac{1}{x^{-p}},$$ 
hence the integral in $(0,1]$ is convergent iff $-p<1$.

Finally, we conclude that the integral in $(0,+\infty)$ is convergent iff $-1<p<2q-1$.

Comment: But for example if we pick 2q-p=2, and have integral 1/x^2, doesn't it  diverge from 0 to infinity? I know such integral converges from 1 to infinity. Don't generally all powers 1/x^n for n it diverges when integral goes from 0 to infinity?

Comment: @Darko Dekan Ok. It is better if we divide $(0,+\infty)$ in two parts $(0,1]$ and $[1,+\infty)$ and check the convergence separately. I edited my answer. Is it clear now?